# RasberryPi python error - sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error - but not in Windows

Tags: python, sql

I have a problem in python code with sqlite3.

This is my code.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db", isolation_level=None)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("WITH T AS (\
    SELECT dense_rank() over(partition by code order by win desc, profit desc, ma asc) as rank, * \
    FROM ENV_ANALYZE WHERE LOSE = 0\
    )\
    SELECT code, name, ma, percent, cutLength, profit, win, lose FROM T where rank = 1")
```

In windows, It works!! There is no problem.

So,I copied this code to RasberryPi. But It occurs error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/python/test.py", line 27, in <module>
    SELECT code, name, ma, percent, cutLength, profit, win, lose FROM T where rank = 1")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

So I fixed like this for a test, It works in RasberryPi anyway. Removed dense_rank option.

```
c.execute("WITH T AS (\
    SELECT 1 as rank, * \
    FROM ENV_ANALYZE WHERE LOSE = 0\
    )\
SELECT code, name, ma, percent, cutLength, profit, win, lose FROM T where rank = 1")
```

But I need that dense_rank option. So I need the first code and I want to Run in RasberryPi.

Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Without more information it is hard to say definitely what causes this problem, but it is probably related to a difference in python and or SQLite version between your window machine and the raspberry pi: try running `python --version` and `sqlite3 --version` to see what versions you have on both machines.

Comment: On a probably unrelated note: perhaps try using triple quotes: ``"""` for a multiline string, that way you don't have to put a backslash after every line of the sql query.

Comment: python 3.5.3 ,  sqlite 3.16.2

Comment: Thank  you for your attention. I fixed code using triple quotes. It work in Windows. But not works in RasberryPi with same Error.

Comment: I found In Windows, sqlite version is 3.31.1 . I'll Try to Upgrade sqlite in  RasberryPi. Thank you Matt.